# Web browser plugin to pause JavaScript execution?

Tags: automated-testing

I have dynamic elements appearing and disappearing on our Web site, e.g., notification balloons.

To understand element, id, tag name, etc. corresponds to this elements I usually click "Inspect element" in the context menu and try to analyze corresponding HTML code. However, sometimes the elements disappears too quickly and HTML source code gets updated as well.

I think there is a JavaScript responsible for closing those elements, so I wonder...

Is there a way/Browser plugin that let me stop JavaScript execution by the user?

I don't want that to be easy, so nothing like putting breakpoints in JavaScript debug mode.

Comment: Some suggestions found: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/Xxyp0s0cHFc

Answer (score 1):

If I am trying to do this for automation, sometimes I add some logging in my automation where I find a parent element and then log the innerhtml for that element.  This way I can see the current state.  You can also see if the notification balloon html exists in the DOM after the balloon disappears, often it is just hidden by styling, but everything else stays the same.

In extreme cases, I have had to use the browser console to put break points in the javascript, which can be complicated if your javascript is compressed, which is pretty common these days.  The other suggestions in the link in your comment also look pretty good.  Using the Event Listener Breakpoints can be helpful.

Comment: I like the idea of logging inner HTML of elements found by WebDriver. Sounds like taking HTML snapshots of elements. I just wonder whether it would be useful to make it more generic, e.g., decorate a  `WebDriver.findElement()` method with feature of logging this information to a separate file. Hmm... Or maybe it's better to leave that only for some special cases?

Comment: I usually just execute javascript to get that, something like this, depending on your programming language: String innerhtml = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", webElement);